# Changing button color after click and resetting it Java

Tags: java, jbutton, actionlistener

```
public class ButtonsActionListener implements ActionListener {    
String[] buttons = { "Button1", "Button2", "Button3", "Button4"};
            for (String btn: buttons ) {
                JButton button = new JButton(btn);
                this.add(button);
                button.addActionListener(this);
            }
        }

   @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JButton btn = (JButton)e.getSource();
            btn.setBackground(Color.Red);
        }


    }
```

What Im trying to do is when the user clicks on for example Button1, Button1's color should turn to grey and when I click on BUtton3, Button1 color should go back to normal and Button3 should turn grey. I dont know how to check the previous click

Comment: Store the button that is currently gray in a variable. Or just iterate over the buttons to find the one that is gray.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks but how do i get the background of the button because im doing String [] buttons not JButton[]  buttons

Comment: You just answered your own question. Store the buttons in an array, or list.

Comment: @JBNizet i get error when i do this.add(buttons);

Comment: Well, why wouldn't you? Your class has no add() method, and doesn't inherit from any class having such a method. You also have most of the code out of any method, making it invalid.

Answer (score -1):

Your `actionPerformed` function changes the background of what is currently clicked, so it will not allow you to change other `JButton` objects without a very rudimentary condition. You should store all of your buttons as unique variables for such cases.

Comment: (1-) `You should store all of your buttons as unique variables for such cases.` - what if you have 100 buttons? Don't do this. Read the suggestions given by JB NIzet.

Comment: The current case only has four buttons, should you always use complex solutions for simple problems?

Comment: `should you always use complex solutions for simple problems? ` - it is NOT a complex solution. It is a simple solution and good design. It is far easier to write a simple loop to iterate through all the buttons then it is to add multiple if/else statements.